# How to validate Nested JSON Response

Tags: api, karate

I am facing issue while validate Nested JSON response in API Testing using Karate Framework.

JSON Response:

```
Feed[
  { "item_type": "Cake" ,
    "title": "Birthday Cake",
    "Services":
     [
        {
        "id": "1",
        "name": {
            "first_name": "Rahul",
            "last_name": "Goyal"
         }
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name":{
            "first_name": "Hitendra",
            "last_name": "garg"
           }
        }    

     ]
  },
  {
    "item_type":"Cycle",
    "title": "used by"
   },

  {
    "item_type": "College"
    "dept":
    [
         {"branch": "EC"},
         {"branch": "CSE"},
         {"branch": "CIVIL"}
    ]

  },

]
}
```

Now i need to validate response based on Item type. as we can see nested JSON is different for different item_type.

I have tried with below solution

## Schema Design for Item_type  value cake

- def Feed_Cake_Service_name={first_name: '#string',last_name: '#string'}
- def Feed_Cake_Services= {id: '#string',name:#(Feed_Cake_Service_name)}
- def Feed_Cake={item_type:'#string',title: '#string',Services: '#[] Feed_Cake_Services'}
- def Feed_Cake_Response= {Feed: '#[] Feed_Cake'}

## Schema Design for item_type Cycle

- def Feed_Cycle={item_type:'#string',title:'#string'}

## Schema Design for item type College

- def Feed_College_Dept_Branch={branch:'#string'}
- def Feed_College={item_type:'#string',dept: '[] Feed_College_Dept_Branch'}

now if i want to verify only item type Cake then i have written match like below

- match response contains Feed_Cake_Response

but here my test case is getting failed. because it is comparing for all item type.

so here i have two question

1.) How we can compare particular item type schema

2.) How we can include all item type in one match equation since any item type can come in JSON response , and i want to validate all

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just give you one hint. For the rest, read the [documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#optional-fields) please:

```
* def item = { item_type: '#string', title: '##string', dept: '##[]', Services: '##[]' }
* match each response == item
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thomas for you help
I am able to verify JSON Response as per your suggestion.
As i can see you have mentioned let say dept:'##[]' it means dept schema can be null or can have some value. but in my case schema is changing based on item_type. so what i am thinking , is Karate allow to use if else condition response matching? or if not then Could you please give me some hint to do this.Thanks

Comment: @ShivamGupta yes, but. ask a new question please with a clear (single, simple) example.